# MySql Trigger Issue variable not referencing in Command String

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have table 'ABANDON' with the following fields,

```
ID  bigint(40)  
CALLID  varchar(100)        
STATUS  varchar(10)
```

Whenever a CALLID is inserted for an abandoned call, I pass it to a shell script for processing,

Here is my trigger,

```
DELIMITER @@
CREATE TRIGGER abandon_insert AFTER INSERT ON ABANDON
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
         DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
         DECLARE result int(10);
         DECLARE ckey varchar(100);
         SET ckey := NEW.CALLID;      
         SET cmd="/usr/bin/tellabandon ckey";
         SET result = sys_exec(cmd);      
    END;
    @@
DELIMITER ;
```

I am unable to assign the column value to the variable.

In my SET Command string, I get the referenced value as "ckey" and not the actual value of the column assigned to the variable.

What could be wrong ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your set statement, "ckey" is part of the literal string.

```
= "/usr/bin/tellabandon ckey";
                        ^^^^
```

To get the *value* of the `ckey` variable, you can concatenate the literal string and the value of the variable

```
 = CONCAT("/usr/bin/tellabandon ",ckey);
```

---

IMPORTANT NOTE: Consider the behavior you could potentially get if `ckey` contains something nefarious, by way of some assigning something nefarious to `CALLID` column, e.g.

```
 'foo && rm -f /tmp/*'
```

or

```
 '`rm -f /tmp/*`'
```

(I'm not sure what it's possible to pass into `sys_exec`, what kinds of checks it does, but it seems pretty dangerous to me.)

Also, be aware that string concatenation with a NULL value results in NULL.

You may want to consider some checks as to what kinds of values you are going to allow, escaping potentially dangerous characters, etc.